# SSL : sec_error_unknown_issuer

Tags: firefox, ssl, security

I'm getting the sec_error_unknown_issuer on my website : https://www.lceonline.co.uk/

The error occurs when I add an item to the cart then click checkout (The checkout page seems to cause it) The SSL Certificate is with Globasign

It seems that this error only occurs in Firefox. Does anyone have a solution or can point me in the direction of one? Little bit of a struggle.

Cheers Guys

Comment: It is not a good idea to publish a phpinfo() page to the world as it discloses sensitive configuration and version information that can be used by a malicious user to focus further attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each browser has an installed list of what is called "Root Certificates". If the issuer's certificate is not in this database, then the browser will reject the cert with the message that you are seeing.

Firefox and Internet Explorer use independent lists of root certs. You may want to speak to your issuer, or a different issuer, about getting you a cert that is acceptable in all major browsers.

It should also be noted that a cert can be denied by the browser with a similar error if it depends on intermediate certificates in the cert-chain and the server has not been correctly configured to deliver *all* the required certs to the browser. This can be tricky to diagnose as browsers will cache and re-use intermediate certs, even if they were originally requested from a different server.

Comment: Thanks for that, going to chase up hosts about this.

Comment: added comment about correct presentation of intermediate certs